# Why does Jest run assertions before componentDidMount finishes executing (using React Test Renderer)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

[Here](https://github.com/evian-pring/JestAsyncTest) is the repo for this question if you want to directly reproduce.

I have a freshly created react-native project (I think it is not important whether it is React or React-Native for this question). I have one single component `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import actions from './actions';

export class App extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log('In CDM');
    await actions.funcOne();
    await actions.funcTwo();
    console.log('Finished CDM');
  }

  render() {
    return <View />;
  }
}
```

Here are two functions that that component is importing from `actions.js`:

```
const funcOne = async () => {
  console.log('One');
};

const funcTwo = async () => {
  console.log('Two');
};

export default { asyncOne: funcOne, asyncTwo: funcTwo };
```

And here is a test I wrote:

```
import React from 'react';
import { App } from '../App';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import actions from '../actions';

const spyOne = jest.spyOn(actions, 'funcOne');
const spyTwo = jest.spyOn(actions, 'funcTwo');

describe('App ', () => {
  test('does async stuff in expected order', async () => {
    console.log('Starting test');
    const tree = await renderer.create(<App />);
    console.log('About to expect');
    expect(spyOne).toHaveBeenCalled();
    console.log('Expect one to have been called');
    expect(spyTwo).toHaveBeenCalled();
    console.log('Expect two to have been called');
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Here is the result of running the test:
[image]

As can be seen, the second `expect` assertion is being called before the function `funcTwo` is executed in `componentDidMount`.

What I am actually trying to accomplish is I have a much more complex component that executes an async function (that makes API calls for example) in `componentDidMount`. I want my test to create the component tree, and assert that the component actually did make the calls to the relevant functions.

I actually found a "solution" (it makes my tests pass and the console.logs appear in the correct order, but I don't understand why it works. The solution is to add the line `await (() => new Promise(setImmediate))();` in the test file right after the line with `await renderer.create`.

**So, I don't want only a solution (though if you have an ideal solution please provide it). I want to know what's going on here, why does the original code not work as expected? **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async / await` is just syntactic sugar for Promises and generators.

When you call `await` you essentially queue the rest of the function in a `then` attached to the `Promise` you are awaiting.

This means that when the `Promise` resolves the rest of the function is added to [PromiseJobs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) queue.

`Promise` callbacks in the PromiseJobs queue run *after the current message completes*...which means that any synchronous code will complete before the callback has a chance to run.

In this case this line runs:

```
await actions.funcOne();
```

...which calls `funcOne` synchronously.  It resolves immediately so the rest of `componentDidMount` is placed in the PromiseJobs queue and execution returns to the test.  (Note that calling `await` on `renderer.create` doesn't wait for the `Promise` returned by `componentDidMount`).

The rest of the test is synchronous so it runs the first `expect` which passes, then runs the second `expect` which fails since the rest of `componentDidMount` is still waiting in the PromiseJobs queue.

To get the test to pass, you just need to give the callback queued in PromiseJobs a chance to run.

As you found, that can be done with this line:

```
await (() => new Promise(setImmediate))();
```

...but even easier is just to `await` a resolved `Promise`:

```
await Promise.resolve();
```

This will queue the rest of the *test* at the back of the PromiseJobs queue behind the callback that will call `actions.funcTwo` and the test will pass.

Here is a slightly simplified example to demonstrate:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

const f1 = jest.fn();
const f2 = jest.fn();

class App extends React.Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    await f1();
    await f2();
  }
  render() { return null; }
}

test('does async stuff in expected order', async () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<App />);
  expect(f1).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
  await Promise.resolve();  // <= let any callbacks in PromiseJobs run
  expect(f2).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
});
```